# How to detect element added from dev tool inspector using MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, jquery, mutation-observers, mutation

In MutationObserver, I am able to capture changes are being added to HTML pages but I am not being able to detect whether the changes are added by inspector or jquery events like onChange()/onBlur()/keyup() etc.

Below is the code which I implemented with MutationObserver.

```
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutationRecords) {
    var list = document.querySelector('body');
    $.each(mutationRecords, function(index, mutationRecord) {             
       console.info(mutationRecords); // Able to detect changes
       // Do something to detect changes being added from inspector or jquery action
    });
});
mutationObserver.observe(document.body, whatToObserve);
```

I want to restrict the changes added by dev tool inspector so I need to know whether the changes added from inspector or not. Above code is detecting the changes but it's not specifying the changes are from inspector or by jquery events.

Comment: The code doesn't make any sense, however it still should print the records in all those mentioned cases. You're not telling us the full story.